# schtasks /create escape character?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

Alright. So. None of these create the scheduled task correctly with %DATE% and %TIME%:

SCHTASKS /Create /TN MyTask /TR "echo %DATE% %TIME% >> C:\SchtaskLog.txt" /SC MINUTE
SCHTASKS /Create /TN MyTask /TR "echo ^%DATE^% ^%TIME^% >> C:\SchtaskLog.txt" /SC MINUTE
SCHTASKS /Create /TN MyTask /TR "echo \%DATE\% \%TIME\% >> C:\SchtaskLog.txt" /SC MINUTE
SCHTASKS /Create /TN MyTask /TR "echo `%DATE`% `%TIME`% >> C:\SchtaskLog.txt" /SC MINUTE

How does one escape a command-line argument with environment variables to be evaluated later?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

SCHTASKS /Create /TN MyTask /TR "cmd /c echo \"^%^date% ^%^TIME%\" >> C:\SchtaskLog.log" /SC MINUTE  /F

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to work if you wrap the command in a .cmd file.  Put this into a .cmd file:

```
@echo %date% %time%
```

And then run this cmd:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /TN MyTask /TR "emittime.cmd >> C:\Log.txt" /SC MINUTE
```

it does what I think you want.